# data-color attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I was working on change fonts color with a panel windows for the user who can choose the color he want but its not working here the HTML code

```
  <div class="style-chooser">
        <div class="style-chooser-inner">
            <a href="#" class="toggoler hide-icon">show-hide-button</a>
            <ul class="preset-list">
                <h4 class="">
                    Preset Color</h4>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="preset1">

                    <img src="../Assets/images/switcher/preset1.png" alt="Preset1" />
                    </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="preset2">
                    <img src="../Assets/images/switcher/preset2.png" alt="Preset2"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="preset3">
                    <img src="../Assets/images/switcher/preset3.png" alt="Preset3" class=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="preset4">
                    <img src="../Assets/images/switcher/preset4.png" alt="Preset4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="preset5">
                    <img src="../Assets/images/switcher/preset5.png" alt="Preset5"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-color="preset6">
                    <img src="../Assets/images/switcher/preset6.png" alt="Preset6"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i already implement jquery into my page but its still not working

i dont know why the data-color not working?

here image for what i mean for more details
[image]

Comment: provide your jquery code?

Comment: what is  `data-color`..? and why it should work..?

Comment: data-color is attribute in HTML5 please see the photo to get the clear idea about what i mean its not change the fonts in the page depend on the color the use pick

Comment: `data-color` means NOTHING. The script does something.

Answer (score 0):

In html5 there is a input type color
this code works in Chrome
Check the support for this feature at http://caniuse.com/input-color

```
<input type="color" value="#008040">
```